# Define a topology of locally uniform convergence on $Y^X$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let X be a top. space and Y a metric space, $f_n, f\in Y^X$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, say that $f_n$ converges locally uniformly to $f$ in case for every $x\in X$ exists some neighbourhood $U_x$ s.t. $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sup\limits_{x\in U_x} d(f(x),f_n(x)) = 0$.

If I didn't get things wrong one can prove that in case $f_n\in C(X,Y)$ also the limit must be continuous: $f\in C(X,Y)$. Now I wondered if one can equip $Y^X$ with a topology $\mathcal{T}$ s.t.:
$$ f_n \text{ converges locally uniformly to } f \quad \iff \quad  f_n \to f \text{ in } \mathcal{T}$$
In this case $C(X,Y)$ would become a sequentially closed subset of $(Y^X, \mathcal{T})$.

In case X is locally compact Hausdorff, then compact convergence is equivalent to local uniform convergence, so one can use the co-topology. But in general I guess the topology should be in between the top. of uniform convergence and the co-top. Thank you!

Comment: I believe this is the [compact-open topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology).

Comment: I think this is only true in case $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff-space where compact and locally uniform convergence coincide.. But maybe I am wrong

Comment: @Lucas You are right.

Answer (score 0):

A sub-base of this topology contains all the sets of the form
$$
U_{f,\varepsilon}=\big\{g: X\to Y: d\big(g(x),f(x)\big)<\varepsilon\big\}
$$
for all $f : X\to Y$ and $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: Shouldn't you vary $O$ open in $X$ (non-empty of course) too and restrict the $x$ to $O$ to define $U(f,\varepsilon,O)$ instead? Now you just get the full uniform convergence topology, not the local one.

Comment: I also think you should vary over the open sets, but in this case $U(f, \epsilon, X)$ must be contained for every $\epsilon > 0$ and so the sequence must already converge uniformly to $f$. But in general locally uniform convergence does not imply uniform convergence. I think there is a problem with "there EXISTS an open neighbourhood" in the definition of locally uniform convergence, where in all other concepts of convergence you require "for all compacta", "for all points", "for X"..